Difference in pattern matching between Cases and ReplaceAll (Already searching at all levels and heads)
Why is there a difference between the pattern matching between Cases and ReplaceAll in the following:
Cases[a*b*c, a*b, All, Heads -> True]
Reap[ReplaceAll[a*b*c, lhs : a*b :> Sow[lhs]]][[2, 1]]


I think the best we have for an answer to this is: Successful match in Replace but not in Cases?
